# What’s the difference between “mis-” and “not-”?

Tags: word-meaning

For example, what’s the difference between “misperceive” and “not perceive”?

[image]

Picture A: B sees the apple A sees, but wrongly. - Misperceive

Picture B: B doesn’t see the apple A sees. - Not perceive

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Tell us what you think it is.

Comment: @Ronald Sole I don’t understand, I’ve already suggested what I think it is with the example…

Comment: Yes. If you don't understand something, it makes no sense to you. If you misunderstand, you get the wrong message from it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you